# material 2 paletta contrast color

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the paletta, I can see contrast.
How can I choose a contrast color?

works:

```
scss
mat-color($button-primary);
```

Not working

```
scss 
mat-color($button-primary, contrast(900));
```

See on the bottom it says contrast.

```
scss
$mat-red: (
  50: #ffebee,
  100: #ffcdd2,
  200: #ef9a9a,
  300: #e57373,
  400: #ef5350,
  500: #f44336,
  600: #e53935,
  700: #d32f2f,
  800: #c62828,
  900: #b71c1c,
  A100: #ff8a80,
  A200: #ff5252,
  A400: #ff1744,
  A700: #d50000,
  contrast: (
    50: $black-87-opacity,
    100: $black-87-opacity,
    200: $black-87-opacity,
    300: $black-87-opacity,
    400: $black-87-opacity,
    500: white,
    600: white,
    700: white,
    800: $white-87-opacity,
    900: $white-87-opacity,
    A100: $black-87-opacity,
    A200: white,
    A400: white,
    A700: white,
  )
);
```

How can I use the contrast?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use custom themes, sometimes it is useful to get the contrast for the default, lighter or darker presets. For example, in your styles.scss you can set the following custom theme:

```
$default-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue, 500, 300, 700);
$default-accent: mat-palette($mat-red, 500, 50, 900);
$default-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);        

$default-theme: mat-light-theme($default-primary, $default-accent, $default-warn);

@include my-component-theme($default-theme);
```

Then, in your component theme you can do the following:

```
@mixin my-component-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

  .test {
      color: mat-color($primary, default-contrast); // or 'lighter-contrast' or 'darker-contrast'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

```
color: mat-contrast($mat-red, 900);
```

Link for reference:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/lib/core/theming/_theming.scss#L4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16762211)

Comment: @Vivz This function, inside the angular material sass, isn't documented.
I updated and add a link from github code that can help understand how this function works.

Comment: I almost missed this because of the -1. This solves my problem, I voted up so people know this is the solution.

Answer (score 10):

The solution is:

```css
.test {
  color: mat-color($button-primary, 900-contrast)
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly for me on angular 14 material theme

Comment: The [docs](https://v9.material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#note-using-the-mat-color-function-to-extract-colors-from-a-palette) actually recommend using `"900-contrast"` with quotes instead

Answer (score 1):

[The current design for that function is this](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/daf7f80847010823995dd3e113ab0ab1f8352ec5/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss#L34).

```
/// For a given hue in a palette, return the contrast color from the map of contrast palettes.
/// @param {Map} $palette The palette from which to extract a color.
/// @param {String | Number} $hue The hue for which to get a contrast color.
/// @returns {Color} The contrast color for the given palette and hue.
@function get-contrast-color-from-palette($palette, $hue) {
  @return map.get(map.get($palette, contrast), $hue);
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
$contrast: mat.get-contrast-color-from-palette($theme-accent, 500);
@debug $contrast;
```

Here's a stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tzuk-tjzksg?file=src%2Fstyles.scss