# How to use Angular Material custom- palette colors effectively Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2, color-palette

I am using a custom material-color palette. 
defined the primary and accent palettes with its default-shade,darker-shade,lighter-shade as below:

```
  $my-app-primary: mat-palette($md-lightprimary ,500,900,A700 );
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($md-lightaccent, 500,900,A100);
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($md-warn);

/*finalize by creating a $my-app-theme variable that combines our color definitions with the mat-light-theme function,*/
$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);
/* and finally include the result of calling the angular-material-theme function with our $my-app-theme.*/
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);
```

**Questions:**

**1.**  If i use in code `color="primary"` or `color="accent"` than it sets the `default` color shade, Question is, how to use the `lighter` and `darker`-shades that we have used as part of initial setting of the theme.

**2.** How to use any other shades from the palette for the `primary` or `accent` shades.

Answer (score 3):

Check the code i written below. check the commented lines for usage

Theme.scss

```
  $my-app-primary: mat-palette($md-lightprimary ,500,900,A700 );
  $my-app-accent:  mat-palette($md-lightaccent, 500,900,A100);
  $my-app-warn:    mat-palette($md-warn);

  $my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn); //gives light theme
  $my-app-dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn); //gives dark version of the above theme

  //apply this class to any element you want to apply dark theme or set class to <body> so apply it to whole site
  .dark-theme { 
      @include angular-material-theme($my-app-dark-theme);
  }
  @include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme); //default theme
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to use the non-default shades from your custom palette by simply modifying the HTML (i.e. `<button color="primary-lighter">` does not work).

The easiest way I've found is to include custom themes in your Theme.scss file, such as:

```
$my-accentpalette: ( 50 : #f9f2eb, ... A700 : #ffae71, contrast: ( 50 : #000000, ..., A700 : #000000, ) );

.lighter-style {
        background-color: mat-color($my-accentpalette, 200);
        color: mat-contrast($my-accentpalette, 200);
}
```

(Note I just picked the '200' entry from the palette, pick whatever you want). Then you can apply the style to any HTML element you want:

```
<button class="lighter-style">
```

Some supporting links that I found helpful:

- [How can I use custom theme palettes in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/how-can-i-use-custom-theme-palettes-in-angular)
- [material 2 paletta contrast color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581477/material-2-paletta-contrast-color)

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar issue with material angular shades. As i cannot find solution (omitting the possibility of using classes that will refer to other theme) in web i used normal scss built-in function such as below:

```
@import "./../../my-theme.scss";

a{
 color: darken($accent, 30%);
}
```